# reverse engineering in C; bomb lab

Tags: c, linux, gdb, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

I am doing a lab for my cs class and we are reverse engineering a "binary bomb". I am confused on a few assembler instructions. If anyone could explain what these do and how the work I would greatly appreciate it.

```
lea   0x10(%rbx), %rbp.
```

Im pretty sure rbx is supposed to hold the address of rbp, but im confused on the 0x10 argument.

```
mov   0x4(%rbx), %eax.
```

Same thing as above, don't understand what the 0x4 argument is.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are offsets (0x10 = 16bytes and 0x4=4bytes) to the pointers in rbp and eax.
Most likely iterating over elements in an array/vector.